# With Mule runtime 4.3.0 we are facing below issue while deploying ,however everything is working fine with 4.2.2 and 4.3.0-20210119 Verstion

Tags: runtime, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

Facing below error with Mule Runtime Version 4.3.0-20210319 While deploying the application  in to couldhud,But same application Working fine with 4.3.0-20210119 and 4.2.2 Version,

Your application has failed with exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.mulesoft.ch.services.agent.muleAgent.MuleAgentException: {"errorType":"class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException", "errorMessage":"There was an error on the Mule Runtime while deploying the application . Error: Failed to deploy artifact []. ConfigurationException: In operation 'pgpEncryptBinary', the following parameters cannot be set at the same time: [pgpKeyInfo, keyId]" }
```

Please help me out here

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in mulesoft and has been acknowledged by them. a fix is expected to come out in july.

Edit:
I have an enterprise support case 00289069 with Mulesoft. ETA for the solution is early July. I talk to their account rep regularly and they confirmed the bug and date. Please keep an eye out for mule patch release notes in July for this fix.

Comment: Could you include a source for this in your answer? This will help provide context for those who come across this issue later on.